# Unknown Cmake command "add_llvm_tool"

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am trying to build llvm from source using Cmake.
I have an error coming when Cmake is trying to build it : Unknown CMake command "add_llvm_tool".

I don't know why there is this error, here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
  ${LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD}
  Core
  Object
  Support
  )

add_llvm_tool(llvm-nm
   llvm-nm.cpp
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `include(AddLLVM.cmake)` to have this macro defined.

Comment: I have to include it in my CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: @Anatch Yes. `.cmake` files usually contain macro definitions that get used in `CMakeLists.txt` files